# Evince keyboard input problem

Tags: 16.04

I recently moved to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I open a PDF on Evince and try to find some word or make a new comment, the software doesn't recognise the keyboard input...Any ideas? The Evince search utility is working because I can copy and paste words into the search field.

I don't have this problem with other sofware as text editors, web browsers, etc. Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same bug, but unfortunately have found no proper solution. The bug seems to be https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1427974 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1587968

Seems that this is caused by enabling "proposed" repository.

Comment: The workaround mentioned in the first bug worked for me `rm -r ~/.config/ibus`